# How to add prefix and suffix text to to part of text in an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to concatenate some block of text with prefix and suffix text.

I already have a working formula which returns the required block of text. The challenge is concatenating it with the prefix and suffix text. I am using this `=ArrayFormula(query(A1:A,,100000))` which allows me to have more than 50,000 characters in a cell. So the prefix needs to come just before `A1:A` and the suffix after.

So that the formula looks something like `=ArrayFormula(query("Prefix"&A1:A&"Suffix",,100000))`. I tried this but it ruins the formula and doesn't return all the results. I'm not sure why.

Here is a link to my spreadsheet -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVQtzoeo3A5g2vjNK1k4yltwEIVQssanw3ulH3a3iH0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SORT(FILTER({"Prefix "&Sheet6!B:B&" Suffix", 
 ROW(Sheet6!A:A)}, Sheet6!A:A=A5), 2, 0),,1),,100000)
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
="Prefix "&QUERY(INDEX(SORT(FILTER({Sheet6!B:B, 
 ROW(Sheet6!A:A)}, Sheet6!A:A=A5), 2, 0),,1),,100000)&" Suffix"
```

[image]

### update 2:

```
=QUERY({"Prefix"; INDEX(SORT(FILTER({Sheet6!B:B, 
 ROW(Sheet6!A:A)}, Sheet6!A:A=A5), 2, 0),,1);"Suffix"},,100000)
```

Comment: The Prefix and Suffix need to appear just once per cell. If you check the current formula there are multiple Prefixes and Suffixes. Maybe I forgot to mention how it should work, sorry.

Comment: It works right but now the error CONCAT is longer than the limit of 50000 characters now shows. So the ```Query(...,,100000)``` part seems to have stopped working.

Comment: @DanstanOngubo dont use concat - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRYuK.png

Comment: Wait, I realized the original random text was cut down to a few text. The formula will work for few characters. The reason I did long sentences in lorem ipsum text is to purposely fall trap of the 50000 characters limit because that's what I'm dealing with.

Comment: @DanstanOngubo updated formula from answer will still handle it

Comment: Please take a look in B14 if you can. Surprisingly, It does not.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I've seen in the `Example Output ==>>`, you only had added `prefix` and `sufix` once to your block of text. You can add them using [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en):

Result: `=concatenate("prefix ",ArrayFormula(query(A1:A,,100000)), " sufix")`

If I'm misunderstanding your question, tell me exactly what result you expect, based on what data.

Comment: Your formula is okay but same error CONCAT is longer than the limit of 50000 characters. Happens only when we add those pieces of text which nullify the purpose of the ```Query(...,,100000)``` part.